# Which was the first sci-fi story featuring time travelling where reality - the present self-heals?

Tags: time-travel, history-of

If I recall correctly, the first time I've read about the idea of the reality-present self-healing after time traveling to the past was in "The Ugly Little Boy" (Isaac Asimov, 1958) where someone tells that if you bring someone from the past to the present, instead of a chain of events that would alter the present, the reality would try to self heal and the present would remain unaltered unless you make a big change in the past.

A more extreme version of this idea is in the *Time Machine* (2002 movie) where the time traveler can't change the fact that his lover died when returning to the past, because that would create a paradox that it would eliminate the motivation for him to create the time machine. I haven't read the original novel of this movie (H.G. Wells 1895) so I don't know if the idea in the novel it's the same.

And I know I've seen an anime recently which featured the same idea in Asimov's way, but I don't remember the name now.

My question is, which was the first sci-fi story to feature this idea? Which was the first sci-fi story featuring time travelling where reality - the present self-heals?

Comment: "self-healing itself" — I think you can just say "self-healing". It's difficult to self-heal something else.

Comment: '—All You Zombies—' or as I sometimes think of it, I'm my own granpa.

Comment: For the record, the *Time Machine* novel has no plot element about a dead lover, or anything involving any paradoxes; the time traveller simply goes straight to the future to see what he can see.

Comment: @jwodder just as further information, the novel was vehicle for a political commentary on the part of Wells. It was the future of capitalism taken to the extreme - the Eloi are the decadent consumerist upper class, while the Molochs are the lower worker class.

Comment: @VLAZ - Morlocks?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *doh*, yes they were actually called "mo**r**loc**k**s". My bad. The name comes from the biblical "Moloch".

Comment: @jwodder - a train-wreck of a Wells/Time Traveller movie is the 1979 _Time After Time_ in which the Time Traveller (who is _HG Wells_) arrives in 1979 California in pursuit of Jack the Ripper who borrowed the TM for a one-way journey to escape the 1895 London police. He meets and falls in love with Mary Steenburgen (who works in a bank) and - long story short - takes her back with him to 1895 where they marry. I was sort of hoping he sent her to stay in Weybridge just before the first Martian cylinder landed, to die by the heat ray, but it seems she died in 1927. So no Wells the serial lover?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch IIRC '—All You Zombies—' used the "consistent history" approach, not quite the same thing as "self-healing" I believe. The difference being that in "consistent history", there is only one timeline - only one past, present, or future - and any attempt to alter it is doomed to be unsuccessful. Whereas it sounds like this "self-healing" approach allows for changes in the past, it just stipulates that historical events are unlikely to be significantly affected by them. (As opposed to the "butterfly effect", where small changes in the past have major effects over time.)

Comment: @DavidZ It was also later then many examples already posted, but that and "By His Bootstraps" are both *interesting* takes on the idea. And then he wrote "—And He Built a Crooked House—" which plays the same kind of games with space.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh, absolutely. Consistent history stories are some of my favorites, though they're disappointingly uncommon. I just wanted to make the point (and make my reasoning clear) that, as far as I can tell, that's not quite the type of time travel being sought here. (And thanks for the reference, I'll have to check out "—And He Built a Crooked House—".)

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question itself, but I can't help but read those tags and think "the history-of time-travel sounds like an inherently convoluted topic".

Comment: @jwodder I've seen neither the Time Machine nor Butterfly Effect, but the time-travel-to-save-the-lover facet sounds like what I've heard of the BE (with Ashton Kutcher?). Minus an actual *machine* for time traveling of course.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[*Hindsight* by Jack Williamson](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2012/08/jack-williamson-hindsight-short-story.html?m=1) from 1940 is the earliest I can recall.

The story is mostly about a war fought against space pirates in the asteroids, but it involves a machine that can view and influence the past.

At the end, the main character argues that while you can change details, there are (more or less) fixed nodes in time that you can't change.

In the story, the "fixed node" was the destruction of the pirate fleet.

The main character determines how the fleet was beaten, and changes the past to fix it.  Despite that, the fleet is still destroyed - by a different cause.  The destruction of the fleet is a given, always.  Only the details change.

Comment: I guess he wrote this before the "butterfly effect" became common knowledge.

Comment: Dr Who seems to have picked up on the same concept, with "fixed points" in time.  It's actually an interesting and somewhat more nuanced way to look at moving around in 4D spacetime -- just as we have heavy or otherwise hard to move objects in 3D, conceptually why wouldn't there be similar "objects" in 4D or higher spacetime?

Comment: @Barmar for me it's a common _myth_

Comment: Regarding the "butterfly effect" as fact vs myth, consider that although a butterfly might be able to affect the location of hurricanes the following year, it won't be able to do much about the rotation rate of the earth. Not everything in nature is chaotic (or at least, the time scales for change can vary by orders of magnitude). The degree to which human events are chaotic is of course up to interpretation, since it's hard to get good data on it.

Answer (score 20):

Just *slightly* earlier than Asimov's *The End of Eternity* (August 1955) is Poul Anderson's "[Time Patrol](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62717)" (**May 1955**).

> "You see, it's rather as if the continuum were a mesh of tough rubber bands. It isn't easy to distort it, **the tendency is always for it to snap back to its, uh, 'former' shape**. One individual insectivore doesn't matter, it's the total genetic pool of their species which led to man.
>
> "Likewise, if I killed a sheep in the Middle Ages, I wouldn't wipe out all its later descendants, maybe all the sheep there were by 1940. Rather, those would still be there, unchanged down to their very genes in spite of a different ancestry — because over so long a period of time, all the sheep, or men, are descendants of all the earlier sheep or men. Compensation, don't you see; somewhere along the line, some other ancestor supplies the genes you thought you had eliminated.
>
> "In the same way... oh, suppose I went back and prevented Booth from killing Lincoln. Unless I took very elaborate precautions, it would probably happen that someone else did the shooting and Booth got blamed anyway.
>
> "That resilience of time is the reason travel is permitted at all. **If you want to change things, you have to go about it just right and work very hard**, usually."

Comment: I was thinking of Bester's "The Men Who Murdered Mohammed" but the Anderson story has the benefit of being earlier.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer or it's the other post's "The End of Eternity". This last story was published later than "Time Patrol" but apparently finished before.

Answer (score 9):

A little bit later, but perhaps a purer example of the trope, is Fritz Leiber’s 1958 short story “Try and Change the Past”, part of his Change War series. The protagonist makes repeated attempts to save his own life, but gives up when his earlier self is hit by a meteorite. It’s online [here](http://sciencefiction.loa.org/biographies/leiber_try_and_change.php).

Answer (score 7):

In Isaac Asimov's *[The End of Eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity)* (1955), Eternity is an organization that exists ostensibly to trade between different times on Earth, but covertly changes history to promote the welfare of humanity as a whole. The time stream tends to heal itself, so changes tend to fade away. For example, most of the same people are born after a change is instituted, even though we know that making a tiny change in the act of conception would lead to embryos developing from different sperm. Physicists these days do not think time would heal itself, incidentally; as *The Butterfly Effect* suggests, the slight changes can result in increasing differences over time. This reality is inconvenient for fiction about time travel, however, so Asimov found a way around it: "self-healing" of the time stream.

Comment: A really great book, mind blowing in lots of ways. However if I remember correcly, time doesn't really heals itself in it. I don't want to spoil the plot, and I would need to re-read it, one of my special abilities is to forget book ends!

Comment: It's been a couple years since I last read End of Eternity, but I don't remember anything about time healing itself in it. Specific quotes would help!

Comment: If I recall correctly, the very begining of the book covers a technician changing the position of an object in a shelf so that, centuries later, space travel would not exist. That was made on purpose, by the way.

Comment: Added an example from memory. I recall Asimov writing of "finding alternate parents" for people, and the protagonist being shocked that his girlfriend simply disappeared after a change to the time line.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron:  The problem with Noÿs was that she shouldn't even have existed in the time line she was in.  She came from a far future that had rediscovered time travel - and also that the time line she came from was very low probability and could only exist as a result of some one tampering with the "natural" course of events.  Changing the current timeline would produce a timeline much like the current one. The computers couldn't predict Noÿs in the modified time lines because she wasn't a product of the existing time lines.

Comment: @JRE True about Noÿs -- but beside the point. The technician's expectation that _most_ people would have "alternate parents" is extremely unrealistic and indicative of a time stream that heals itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you broaden your definitions of science fiction and time-travel, you're basically describing the long-established literary trope of the "self-fulfilling prophecy."  The classic example is Oedipus Rex (performed around 429 B.C.) wherein attempts to change fate actually results in the predicted outcome.  A "self-healing timeline" is nothing more than the principle of Fate applied on timeline that twists, loops, or forks.

Reliable prophesy is informational time-travel (just as many time-loop time travel stories do not actually deal in corporeal or bodily time travel, but informational time-travel in the form of consciousness).  If the rules of the magic are predictable and repeatable they may constitute science fiction.  So any story with a known but unavoidable Fate basically answers the question.

Comment: No, "you can't change the past" is qualitatively different from "you can change the past, but it won't change the present."  Besides, we just covered that [last week](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/241357/101407).

Comment: @DavidW You mean we covered that "next week"?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer We were have been going to have had that covered next week. :)

Comment: Didn't I once read a short story by Asimov where a group of present-day human scientists decide to see if altering the past changes the present, and they make a series of past-alterations, and each time things change in the present but they don't notice? I think it ends up with the team leader ruffling his fine feathers and stroking his beak triumphantly, and they are all saying things like "Awwk Qrzzzt Smmpspddff!"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I believe there are at least 2 like that, one where they say something like "and we still have 6 tentacles, like we've always had" and the other where they go from scientists with an advanced AI to shamans/witch doctors with a magic speaking copper mask.  I'd have to dig for the names though.

Comment: Whilst that's certainly the basis of the concept, those stories typically rely on the "fated" event being different to what the protagonist thought they would be, but still being predictable with cause and effect. With "self-healing time" plots, the concept is more that an entirely different, unpredictable event will occur with the same end result, for values of unpredictable which may (as another answer says) include direct meteorite strikes. It's different enough that I don't think you can really include it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey [Red Dwarf](https://youtu.be/78RHJCQ0mXg) managed to do that entire story in 30 seconds…

Comment: A funny and very original (both in concept and style) variation of the theme is R. A. Lafferty's [*Thus We Frustrate Charlemagne*](https://www.ralafferty.org/works/stories/thus-we-frustrate-charlemagne/) where a group of time travelers sets out repeatedly to change a crucial event in the past and see whether it has any repercussions in the present, after they return. It does, in grandiose fashion, including changes to themselves; but because the past is what it has always been in the particular time line in which they return to the present they cannot know that anything has changed. Hilarious.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You sure it's not Lafferty's story from my other comment?

Comment: I think that this answer has value. @DavidW In a way the oracle is a time traveling device. "Seeing" the future means traveling to it at least virtually, and then back. At the very least it is a special case of "reality self heals" (namely the future reality the oracle saw): The special case where you can change *not a single detail*, try as you might. That is a sub-genre of time travel stories, although usually told from a narrator whose "home time" is the time when the consequences are expected, not where the manipulation was done (but that is only a perspective change).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Did you miss the part where we already had a question about not being able to change the timeline last week?  It's not very useful to ask 2 different questions and insist that they have the same answer.  Obviously if that answer was what OP was looking for they wouldn't have needed to ask a new question.

Comment: @DavidW Yes, I did.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that's by William Tenn *Brooklyn Project* https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211993/28516

Answer (score -1):

This is the very subject of Damon Knight's Anachron, published in 1953/4. There is a discussion of the story at [Seeking story about time travel used to steal from the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71424/seeking-story-about-time-travel-used-to-steal-from-the-future)

Comment: Whilst that may be true a work of 1940 has already been given and we’re looking for the earliest work here. As such I really feel this is more of a comment as it isn’t earlier.